# Android read xml error

Tags: java, php, android, xml, uri

I am trying to read an xml file from android application but xml file is being generated from php instantly (so the file is .php)

When i am asking on that url from java i get this error : Expected file scheme in URI : "http://someserver.com/foo/bar/Myuri.php"

```
try {
          File file = new File(new URI("http://someserver.com/foo/bar/Myuri.php"));
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc = db.parse(file);
          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
          System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
          NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
          //System.out.println("Information of all employees");

          for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

            Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

            if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                   Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
              NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
              Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
              NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
              System.out.println("Name : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
              NodeList lstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("lastname");
              Element lstNmElmnt = (Element) lstNmElmntLst.item(0);
              NodeList lstNm = lstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
              System.out.println("Last Name : " + ((Node) lstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
            }

          }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            alertDialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            alertDialog.show();
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, now we've got some code, let's look at the important line:

```
File file = new File(new URI("http://someserver.com/foo/bar/Myuri.php"));
```

The `File` class is for files. Not arbitrary URIs. It's expecting a `file` scheme in the URI, e.g. `file://`.

Basically, you can't use `File` to get stuff off the web. That's not what it's there for. Use an HTTP library, e.g. [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).

Comment: Also do you send headers in php file ? header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

Comment: @Jon Skeet , yeah that is how i pass it any way , i just didn't mind to mention it !

Comment: @vodich of course i am having the header correct , although the same php i am using on my windows phone application and it works fine

Comment: @DimitrisSapikas: Now you've edited your question to make it look like you've got one error, when you certainly didn't get that *exact* error message. Please show the *exact* error, and ideally some code. Otherwise we're just guessing, given misleading information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: @DimitrisSapikas: There's no "of course" about this at all. You've given us practically no information, and clearly *something's* wrong. If you don't want people to suggest wild guesses, you need to give us a lot more information.

Comment: actualy i am giving the exact error as given by 

catch (Exception e) {
         alertDialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                alertDialog.show();
      }

Comment: @DimitrisSapikas: Your *exact* error message says "`Expected file scheme in URI : "http://someserver.com/foo/bar/Myuri.php"`"? Really? I *happened* to pick the exact URI you're using, including `someserver.com/foo/bar`? I must be a mind reader. Or maybe that's really *not* the exact error you're getting.

Comment: @DimitrisSapikas: Now we've got code, see my edit. You're trying to create a `File` when you shouldn't be.